# Deleting very large table records where id not in another table

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-8.4

I have one table values that have 80 million records. Another table values_history that has 250 million records.

I want to filter the  values_history  table and want to keep the only  data for which id is preset in values table.

```
delete from values_history where id not in (select id from values);
```

This query takes such a long time that I have to abort the process.

Please some idea to speed up the process.

Can I delete the records in bunch like 1000000 at a time?

Comment: You may have to resort to selecting the first crore from values_history and delete those records not present in values, then the next crore etc. Is values_history online or offline? If offline you could copy those present in values and delete the old and rename. But those are huge tables so this may not work in real life. Good luck.

Comment: Performance questions require lots of information and you provided none. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Use `EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`. Do the work in batches. Make sure appropriate indexes exist. It's hard to say much more without relevant information (PostgreSQL version, query plans, etc etc etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extracted out the required record and inserted into temp table .This took 2 hrs after that i dropped the table then again inserted extracted data back to the main table whole process took 4 hrs around that is fine for me.I have dropped foreign key and all other constraint before that..